# wp.data.select('core').getPostType('post-type') returns undefined in Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm building a Wordpress plugin that relies on custom fields being enabled when registering a custom post type. I want to check if the `custom-fields` key exists (and is `true`) in `supports` in the post type object. However, when I call `wp.data.select('core').getPostType('post-type')`, it returns `undefined`. If I call it directly from the console, I get the post type object I expect, so I'm not sure why it isn't working in my code.

I've tried calling this from a few places.

E.g. When registering the plugin panel:

```
// Loading `wp.editPosts`, `wp.plugins`, etc. excluded for brevity.

const Component = () => {
    const postType = wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType();
    const postTypeObj = wp.data.select('core').getPostType(postType);

    if (postTypeObj.supports.hasOwnProperty('custom-fields')) {
        return (
            <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
                name="my-plugin-name"
                title={ __('My Plugin Title', 'pb') }
            >
                <MyPlugin/>
            </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
        );
    }

    return;
};

registerPlugin('my-plugin-name', {
    render: Component,
    icon: '',
});
```

or within the plugin itself via `withSelect`:

```
// Loading `wp.compose`, `wp.data`, etc. excluded for brevity.

class MyPlugin extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            // I'll do something with this later on
            postTypeObj: props.postTypeObj,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export default compose([
    withSelect(select => {
        const {
            getCurrentPostType,
        } = select('core/editor');

        const {
            getPostType,
        } = select('core');

        return {
            postTypeObj: getPostType(getCurrentPostType()),
        }
    }),
])(MyPlugin);
```

No matter where I call it, the post type object returns `undefined`.

I'm using the Gutenberg Plugin, version `6.5.0` and WordPress version `5.2.3`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `getCurrentPostType()` will return e.g. `post`. You may not need to wrap it in `getPostType` too. Also, according to https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13555, you will need to “subscribe” (`wp.data.subscribe`) as this is an asynchronous call, and so will return null the first time you run it.

Comment: subscribing was a bit of a pain, as depending on how much the screen loads, there's several callbacks where post type is still `null` - so don;t `unsubscribe` until you've got a value 

Answer (score 5):

This is characteristic of anything from wp.data.select('core'), and of things built on top of it.

The issue is that react is making an ajax call to get the data. And, when the response comes back, that will trigger another render. So, if you've arranged things with that in mind, your code will run again (when the response arrives), and get a non-null result based on the response from the server which will have been stored for you by then.

Put different: initially things are blanks, and those blanks will get filled in.

(This is worth repeating, so please educate others about this issue.)

Comment: Resume: wait for the second time the function runs. It should work!

Answer (score 4):

For those who needs this functionality under custom post type edit window, there are few requirements.

**1.** When registering custom post type make sure `show_in_rest` is set to `true` and supports array includes `editor`. This will enqueue required scripts.

Or you can manually enqueue them as follows:

```php
function enable_gutenberg_on_custom_post_types( $hook ) {
    global $current_screen;

    // Load on certain post type
    if ( 'product' !== $current_screen->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Make the WP Screen object aware that this is a block editor page.
     * Since custom blocks check whether the screen is_block_editor,
     * this is required for custom blocks to be loaded.
     * See wp_enqueue_registered_block_scripts_and_styles in wp-includes/script-loader.php
     */
    $current_screen->is_block_editor( true );

    /**
     * Fires after block assets have been enqueued for the editing interface.
     *
     * Call `add_action` on any hook before 'admin_enqueue_scripts'.
     *
     * In the function call you supply, simply use `wp_enqueue_script` and
     * `wp_enqueue_style` to add your functionality to the block editor.
     *
     * @since 5.0.0
     */
    do_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enable_gutenberg_on_custom_post_types' );
```

**2.** you need to enqueue other scripts as well, i.e `wp-data` and `wp-edit-posts`:

```php
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-custom-script',
    PLUGIN_URL . 'dist/admin.js',
    array( 'react', 'react-dom', 'wp-data', 'wp-edit-post' ),
    '1.0.0',
    false
);
```

Then in javascript:

```js
window.wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post' )
```

Or using hook:

```js
  const posts = window.wp.data.useSelect((select) => {
    return select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'product');
  }, []);
```